# Is it possible to have TFS fetch email from a POP3 account?

Tags: email, tfs

Is it possible to have TFS 2017 fetch email from Gmail?

For instance...

I have a ticketing system (OS Ticket) on an external server. I have TFS sitting on a private server and would like to have it pull those tickets that are emailed out from OS Ticket to a Gmail account and create tasks within TFS automatically.

- First: If this even remotely possible?
- Second: Can it be done?
- Third: If it can be done, How, are there any examples or is it something seriously easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is able to be achieved, but there is not default way. You have to code your solution which should contain two parts:

1. Filter the emails in ticketing system or in Gmail account. For example, in Gmail, you can filter emails by sender with `criteria.from='sender@example.com'`(check [Managing Filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings) for more information). You would need to get more help from OS Ticket or Gmail side for this part.
2. Use [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) to create a work item: 

   `PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version={version}
   Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
   [
   {
       "op": "add",
       "path": { string }
       "value": { string or int, depending on the field }
   },
   {
       "op": "add",
       "path": "/relations/-",
       "value":
       {
           "rel": { string },
           "url": { string },
           "attributes":
           {
               { name/value pairs }
           }
       }
   }
   ]`

Answer (score -1):

You can buy a product like [TeamBox](http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teambox/features/email-address-monitoring.aspx) or code your solution using TFS API.

It is not trivial to implement a robust solution (you can see a fullly functioning code example in https://github.com/Microsoft/mail2bug), so you need to add some monitoring on top that everything is running smoothly.